# How to inject parameters in Symfony state machine calback class method?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, state-machine, sylius

I need to inject couple of parameters in state machine callback method.

I configured transition callback inside config.yml. But method is called statically therefore can't use constructor injection. When I tried method injection it said that I did not pass all the parameters. Only the first parameter, from the state machine is passed into method.

```
winzou_state_machine:
  sylius_order:
    callbacks:
      after:
        profiler_invoice_email_sender:
          on: ['fulfill']
          do: ['ProfilerBundle\Invoice\InvoiceEmailSender', 'send']
          args: ['object.getNumber()']
```

```php
<?php

namespace ProfilerBundle\Invoice;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\CustomerInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\OrderInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Repository\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Sylius\InvoicingPlugin\Email\InvoiceEmailSenderInterface;
use Sylius\InvoicingPlugin\Entity\InvoiceInterface;
use Sylius\InvoicingPlugin\Repository\InvoiceRepository;

class InvoiceEmailSender
{
    /**
     * @param string $number
     * @param InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository
     * @param InvoiceEmailSenderInterface $invoiceEmailSender
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     */
    public function send(
        string $number,
        InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository,
        InvoiceEmailSenderInterface $invoiceEmailSender,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        /** @var InvoiceInterface $invoice */
        $invoice = $invoiceRepository->getOneByOrderNumber($number);

        /** @var OrderInterface $order */
        $order = $orderRepository->findOneBy(['number' => $invoice->orderNumber()]);

        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();

        $invoiceEmailSender->sendInvoiceEmail($invoice, $customer->getEmail());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass services to arguments by prepending `@` symbol, see https://github.com/winzou/StateMachineBundle/blob/master/spec/winzou/Bundle/StateMachineBundle/Callback/ContainerAwareCallbackSpec.php#L23